# JDBC numeric overflow in select statement

Tags: java, jdbc

I have a java application that executes SQL select statements entered by the user on the UI. The application gets the metadata to know the column types:

```
ResultSetMetaData metadata = rs.getMetaData();
int numColumns = metadata.getColumnCount();
for (int i=1;i<=numColumns;i++){
    column[i] = metadata.getColumnType(i);  
}
```

Once I get the result set, for each row I loop through the columns to know the types. Depending on the type I get the values with getInt(), getDate() or getString().

The problem is that in some cases where the select has a large SUM(), there's a numeric overflow when I do getInt() (I get an error from the JDBC driver, Sybase in my case). The problem is that the number to be obtained in getInt() is larger than the capacity of int.

One solution is to use getLong() instead of getInt(), however since I don't know beforehand the select columns as they're entered by the user, I may be using getLong() for very small numeric values, and in large volumes that would be a complete waste of 64-bit fields.

Any ideas how to solve this problem?

Comment: You could use a `BigDecimal` for any known numerical column...

Comment: I don't think you are really *that* hungry for saving those 64 bits ;) Maybe the question is: Do you really think you'll get a big performance penalty if using `long` instead of `int` for those columns?

Comment: Keep it simple. Always use the next larger data type (`long` in this case) if the user wants a `SUM` on a numeric column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the age of 64 Bit CPUs, maybe `getLong()` wouldn't be such a waste after all. But even `getLong()` might overflow, so you're safer but not completely safe. `BigDecimal` puts you on the safe side. And since you describe the application as a *UI* in which the *user enters the statements*, the bottleneck will most likely be the user itself or JDBC, not Java.

You can use `ResultSetMetaData.getColumnType(int column)` to determine the type of the column and choose a Java type based on that. And you could use `ResultSetMetaData.getColumnClassName(int column)` to find out what Java class the driver suggests, and use `ResultSet.getObject(int column)` to retrieve the data. Whether that is really convenient might also depend on the quality of the driver.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you always use the next larger data type (`long` in this case for an `int` column) when the user wants a `SUM` on a numeric column.

The reason is because you're going to expend at least that much memory and processing trying to figure out which data type to use anyhow. You may as well keep your code simple and promote to the next larger type.

Answer (score 0):

You could do "optimistic" buffering for your columns: Start out with `int` (or even `short`) buffers for your column data and wrap your fetch loop in a `try`/`catch` for that overflow exception. If you catch one, check how wide you need your buffer datatype to be by trying to retrieve it as increasingly "wide" (`short` -> `int` -> `long` -> `BigInteger`/`BigDecimal`) types. Then resize the buffer for that column (by allocating a new buffer of the wider type and copying over the values from previous rows) and restart your retrieval.

But this is pretty complicated code. If you can afford the memory, you'd be better off just using `long` or `BigInteger`/`BigDecimal` instead. You should examine the actual sizes and resultant memory savings on some example data sets. (And be aware there's a bit of a cost for the buffer reallocation when you do end up having to widen.) If the result set size in practice fits easily in memory for your users with the simpler `long` or wider retrievals, then there isn't a problem and you don't have to solve it.